# Project Euler Problem 1 with Python 3 ideal solution

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I have been playing around in hacker rank with Python these days, and now pulling my hair out on this [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001) to solve the Euler's problem in the least time required.

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

Without that in mind, I initially wrote the below code:

> ```
> t = int(input())
> for a in range(t):
>     n = int(input())
>     temp=0
>     for i in range(n):
>         if(i%3==0 or i%5==0):
>             temp+=i
>     print(temp)
> ```

The above solves most of the test cases except #2 and #3 in HackerRank. On checking the discussion tab, I found out that we have to reduce the time required to avoid timeout as the #2 and #3 test cases inputs big numbers.

Can anyone help me to optimize my code further?

Comment: **Code not implemented or not working as intended**: Code Review is a community where programmers peer-review your working code to address issues such as security, maintainability, performance, and scalability. We require that the code be working [correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650), before proceeding with a review.

Comment: The code in the question work for 4 out of 6 cases, and HackeRank does not reveal the test cases so I asked if there is any way to improve the performance of the above code.

Comment: Try using the fact that \$3+6+9+...+3n = 3(1+2+3+...+n) = \frac{3n(n+1)}{2}\$, and see what you can do with that.

Comment: If your first code runs without a `RuntimeError` and just generates a time-out, that part would be on-topic (and you should add the tag [tag:time-limit-exceeded]).

Comment: @Graipher updated the question with time limit. And thank you maxb I will try that as well.

Comment: If it still gives a runtime error, it's not ready for review.

Comment: The second code gives a runtime error, the first one gives a timeout error @Mast

Comment: I've removed the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` isn't a great name for your accumulator.  Call it something like `total`, which gives a much clearer indication of what role it plays.

First, let's separate the logic from the I/O, to make it easier to test:

```
def sum_3s_and_5s(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if (i%3==0 or i%5==0):
            total+=i
    return total

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sum_3s_and_5s(10))
```

We can now focus on the implementation of `sum_3s_and_5s`.  We can write the same algorithm more succinctly:

```
def sum_3s_and_5s(n):
    return sum([i * (i%3==0 or i%5==0) for i in range(n)])
```

This doesn't change the time complexity, of course - it still scales as O(*n*).  What we need to do is think about the mathematics.  What we're looking for is the sum of all the multiples of 3 in the range, added to all the multiples of 5, less the multiples of 15 (which are otherwise double-counted).  Let's write a function to count multiples of *k* in a given range:

```
def sum_multiples(n, k):
    return sum([i * (i%k==0) for i in range(n)])

def sum_3s_and_5s(n):
    return sum_multiples(n,3) + sum_multiples(n,5) - sum_multiples(n, 15)
```

You might not think that's an improvement - and you'd be right, because we're now reading the whole range three times instead of once.  But we can work or `sum_multiples`, to make it O(*1*).  Remember the formula for triangular numbers: sum(i){0,n} = ½n(n+1).  The sum of all the multiples of *k* is just *k* times the sum of integers from 0 to n/k.  That gives us:

```
def sum_multiples(n, k):
    # subtract 1 from n, as range is exclusive
    n = (n-1) // k
    return k * n * (n + 1) // 2
```

Now it doesn't matter how big *n* gets, the calculation is constant time (or perhaps O(log *n*) if we get into big integers).